# Which kernel produces sharper image

Tags: image-processing, filters, fourier-transform, frequency-spectrum, highpass-filter

kernel `A =`

```
[ 0 -1 0
 -1 4 -1 
  0 -1 0 ]
```

and `B =`

```
[-1 0 -1
  0 4 0
 -1 0 -1 ]
```

i have found the frequency spectrums with `freqz2` function of Matlab.

`A`'s spectrum has the highest magnitudes in the corners `(1,1),(-1,-1),(1,-1),(-1,1)` 
and `B`'s in `(1,0),(0,1),(-1,0),(0,-1)`.

I know that the center of the frequency spectrum has the low frequency information and the corners the high frequency information such as edges. It appears that `B` filter produces a sharper image although `A` has higher magnitude in the corners. Why is this happening ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sharpness of an image depends on [acutance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acutance) and resolution. The [quantification of image sharpness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646371/detect-which-image-is-sharper) seems image content dependent to me, since (i) sometimes the noise at the low SNR region may be enhanced with an high-pass kernel, and (ii) your `A` and `B` work on the edges with different orientations.

Take a very simple example:

```
T = [1 0 1;...
     0 1 0;...
     1 0 1];
```

`conv(T,A,'same')` gives you

```
   [4  -3  4;...
    -3  4  -3;...
    4  -3  4];
```

while `conv(T,B,'same')` results in:

```
   [3 0 3;...
    0 0 0;...
    3 0 3];
```

Looks like kernel `A` is better in sharpening the 45 degree edges. Yet with

```
  T = [0 1 0;...
       1 1 1;...
       0 1 0];
```

The performance of two kernels looks reversed (`B` appears to be better in horizontal and vertical edges enhancement).